Using concrete as an edging restraint for a paver patio
I've been seeing a lot of references to using concrete as an edge restraint for pavers. I am more familiar with the plastic edge restraints. With the plastic type, you install them before you do the final compacting and as the pavers settle 1/4"-3/8" the plastic edge restraints keep them in place.
Now I'm trying to imagine how that would work with concrete edging. I want to install the edging restraint before I do the final compacting, but If I have used concrete, the concrete will have adhered to the outermost pavers and they wont be able to settle downwards as the final compacting is happening.
Maybe the concrete edging is added after the final compacting? But, then I think the final compacting will move the outermost pavers out of position since there is nothing to restrain them from moving.
What am I not understanding here?

to keep the pawers from moving at the edge, one uses a concrete layer under the edge pawers so they stick to it, not visible afterwards

But then, when you do the final compacting, won't those edge pavers be higher than the rest of the patio since the concrete will prevent them from settling along with the rest of the pavers?

no they want, the concrete is very thin, just to hold pawers in place

@irrational there are different ways of using concrete to edge a patio; this video may help you visualize: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FfYjesRpOYQ

The second option is the one I'm referring to.

If you are not able to allow the concrete to set up a day or 2 before compacting, or would just like to do poly & compacting before edging, you can use a 2x4 pushed right against the edge of the pavers and drive grade stakes every 3' or so to re-enforce the 2x4.
along curves use old pvc board w/ the same concept.
I have never had a problem with the concrete preventing pavers from setting (as long as you are just doing edging and not setting the perimeter pavers in a concrete bed)
Typically the vibration and force of the tamper will easily break the bond between paver and edge. If you are having that issue i would recommend adding less water for a more "stiff" mix
